# How to solve "LoadError: could not load library compiling error" probably coming from PyPlot, in Juno command prompt?

Tags: compilation, include, julia, juno-ide

When I try to compile my Julia file in a Julia command prompt, as so :

```
julia> include("file.jl")
```

it shows me this error, which I can't wrap my head around :

```
[ Info: Precompiling PyPlot [d330b81b-6aea-500a-939a-2ce795aea3ee]
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: could not load library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Stacktrace:
[1] dlopen(::String, ::UInt32) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux32/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Libdl/src/Libdl.jl:97
 [2] top-level scope at /home/toto/.julia/packages/PyCall/zqDXB/src/startup.jl:47 [inlined]
 [3] top-level scope at ./none:0
 [4] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [5] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [6] include at ./sysimg.jl:29 [inlined]
 [7] include(::String) at /home/toto/.julia/packages/PyCall/zqDXB/src/PyCall.jl:1
 [8] top-level scope at none:0
 [9] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [10] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [11] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [12] top-level scope at none:2
 [13] eval at ./boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [14] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:393
 [15] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /home/toto/.julia/packages/PyCall/zqDXB/src/startup.jl:41
in expression starting at /home/toto/.julia/packages/PyCall/zqDXB/src/PyCall.jl:34
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile PyCall [438e738f-606a-5dbb-bf0a-cddfbfd45ab0] to /home/toto/.julia/compiled/v1.0/PyCall/GkzkC.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1203
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:960
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:858
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:853
 [6] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [7] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [8] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [9] top-level scope at none:2
 [10] eval at ./boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [11] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:393
 [12] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /home/toto/.julia/packages/PyPlot/XHEG0/src/PyPlot.jl:4
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: Failed to precompile PyPlot [d330b81b-6aea-500a-939a-2ce795aea3ee] to /home/toto/.julia/compiled/v1.0/PyPlot/oatAj.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1203
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:960
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:858
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:853
 [6] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [7] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [8] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [9] include(::String) at ./client.jl:392
 [10] top-level scope at none:0
 [11] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [12] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [13] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [14] include(::String) at ./client.jl:392
 [15] top-level scope at none:0
 [16] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [17] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [18] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [19] include(::String) at ./client.jl:392
 [20] top-level scope at none:0
in expression starting at /home/toto/project/code/julia/file3.jl:1
in expression starting at /home/toto/project/code/julia/file2.jl:2
in expression starting at /home/toto/project/code/julia/file.jl:1
```

How do I solve this?
I note that I have installed PyPlot :

```
julia> import Pkg; Pkg.add("PyPlot")
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml`
 [no changes]
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Manifest.toml`
 [no changes]
```

I also note that I am getting this error in a second Julia command window using Juno, since Juno's standard REPL is occupied running some other code. This other code in REPL includes my "faulty" files `file.jl, file2.jl` and `file3.jl` as well, and runs just fine there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved itself after I tried to open a second REPL by clicking in the menu bar `Juno -> Open External REPL`, instead of my initial `Juno -> New Terminal -> Current File's Folder`.